# Xdebug Netbeans waiting for connection

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

Xdebug using Netbeans seems to be crashing every other page load.
On the second load Netbeans just sits waiting for connection without opening the designated browser - Firefox.
On restarting Netbeans (a pain) everything works fine for one page load.
Then back to the above issues.
So Xdebug is configured okay as it works once, but why is it necessary to re-start Netbeans everytime ?

Answer (score 0):

I realised that while the script I was working on had a manual execution point, there was also an auto one triggered by Task Scheduler every minute.
This explains restarting Netbeans and xdebug worked for one run - it seems that shortly after it would be triggered by auto schedule which is somehow crashing xdebug silently and preventing it restarting without a complete restart of Netbeans - not sure why though.